change default docroot in glassfish via glassfish-web.xml
Hello As you know the default docroot in glassfish is domain/docroot and I need change it to another location with glassfish-web.xml file, as I search all answers is about add another docroot like :
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/uploads/* dir=/path/to/your/uploaded/files"/>
</glassfish-web-app>

but what can I do for default docroot?
I need change default docroot not added another docroot.
I don't want change Glassfish virtual-server or server.
